# Use (include/require) the same file twice

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a perl script (MyTest.pl) that includes (use) two modules (MyA.pm and MyB.pm). 
The problem I have is that module A also have to include Module B, but this doesn't seem to work as is already has been included in the .pl file.

**MyTest.pl**

```
use MyA;
use MyB;
print hello(); # defined in MyB
```

**MyA.pm**

```
use MyB;
print hello(); # defined in MyB
```

perl states that the subroutine **hello** is undefined when called from MyA.pm. From what I can grasp it seems like the **use** only works where it is used (ha!) the first time.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show us an `import` method for `MyB` or tell us if it inherits the `import` method of a standard module like `Exporter`.
Without an `import` method, the `MyB::hello` subroutine can't be aliased into the `Main` or `MyA` namespaces.

Your 2 choices are to do the import or to use the full name of `MyB::hello`.

Edit:
Hmm, I also notice that you're not using a `package` name in `MyA`.  Are your modules all using the `Main` namespace as their personal litter box?

Comment: I am exporting the `hello` function using `Exporter`. But you helped me, I was not using `package` in `MyB`. It works now, thanks.

Comment: That's interesting.  I wonder what `*Main::hello` looks like after you `import` `&Main::hello` into it's own namespace.  I can't imagine it's good.  Fodder for another day....